# Azure deployment fails running Gulp

Tags: azure, gulp, azure-deployment

Everything builds fine locally, but when deploying to Azure I get the following error.

[image]

After the build fails, I've checked the Azure console and have the following version numbers

[image]

Commands I'm running on build

```
<Exec Command="npm install" /> 
<Exec Command="npm install -g less" /> 
<Exec Command="npm install -g gulp@3.9.1" />
<Exec Command="npm install -g gulp-cli" /> 
<Exec Command="npm install -g gulp-less" /> 
<Exec Command="npm install -g gulp-rename" /> 
<Exec Command="npm install --save-dev gulp-cssmin" />
<Exec Command="npm install --save-dev gulp-babel @babel/core @babel/preset-env" />
<Exec Command="gulp default" />
```

And finally... the gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
less = require('gulp-less'),
babel = require('gulp-babel'),
cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
rename = require('gulp-rename');
/*concat = require('gulp-concat')*/


/*
 * Path variables
 */
const paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};

paths.js = paths.webroot + "js/app/**/*.js";
paths.transpiledJsPath = paths.webroot + "js/transpiled";
paths.siteLess = paths.webroot + "css/site.less";
paths.compiledSiteCssPath = paths.webroot + "css";


/*
 * Tasks
 */
gulp.task('less', () => 
    gulp.src(paths.siteLess)
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.compiledSiteCssPath))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.compiledSiteCssPath))
);

gulp.task('transpile', () =>
    gulp.src(paths.js)
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['@babel/env']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.transpiledJsPath))
);

/*gulp.task('transpile-bundle', () =>
    gulp.src(paths.js)
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['@babel/env']
    }))
    .pipe(concat('transpiled-bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.transpiledJsPath))
);*/

gulp.task("default", ["less", "transpile"/*, "transpile-bundle"*/]);
```

Upgrading the Gulp CLI version in Azure seems to be impossible so upgrading to Gulp 4 is NOT an option.

The error in question seems to occur because it's expecting Gulp 4 syntax, so I tried updating to Gulp 4 syntax and I get an error like it's expecting Gulp 3 syntax. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Is there good news by trying the below solution? Feel free to leave comment below if you still facing any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `default` task to:

```js
gulp.task("default", gulp.series("less", "transpile"));
```